# elasticsearch boosting slowing query

Tags: elasticsearch

this is a very novice question but I'm trying to understand how 
boosting certain elements in a document works.

I started with this query,

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 6,
  "fields": [
    "_id"
  ],
  "sort": {
    "_score": "desc",
    "vendor.name.stored": "asc",
    "item_name.stored": "asc"
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "_all"
          ],
          "query": "Calprotectin",
          "default_operator": "AND"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "targeted_countries"
                ],
                "query": "All US"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then i needed to boost certain elements in the document more than the others 
so I did this

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 60,
  "fields": [
    "_id"
  ],
  "sort": {
    "_score": "desc",
    "vendor.name.stored": "asc",
    "item_name.stored": "asc"
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "item_name^4",
            "vendor^4",
            "id_plus_name",
            "category_name^3",
            "targeted_countries",
            "vendor_search_name^4",
            "AdditionalProductInformation^0.5",
            "AskAScientist^0.5",
            "BuyNowURL^0.5",
            "Concentration^0.5",
            "ProductLine^0.5",
            "Quantity^0.5",
            "URL^0.5",
            "Activity^1",
            "Form^1",
            "Immunogen^1",
            "Isotype^1",
            "Keywords^1",
            "Matrix^1",
            "MolecularWeight^1",
            "PoreSize^1",
            "Purity^1",
            "References^1",
            "RegulatoryStatus^1",
            "Specifications/Features^1",
            "Speed^1",
            "Target/MoleculeDescriptor^1",
            "Time^1",
            "Description^2",
            "Domain/Region/Terminus^2",
            "Method^2",
            "NCBIGeneAliases^2",
            "Primary/Secondary^2",
            "Source/ExpressionSystem^2",
            "Target/MoleculeSynonym^2",
            "Applications^3",
            "Category^3",
            "Conjugate/Tag/Label^3",
            "Detection^3",
            "GeneName^3",
            "Host^3",
            "ModificationType^3",
            "Modifications^3",
            "MoleculeName^3",
            "Reactivity^3",
            "Species^3",
            "Target^3",
            "Type^3",
            "AccessionNumber^4",
            "Brand/Trademark^4",
            "CatalogNumber^4",
            "Clone^4",
            "entrezGeneID^4",
            "GeneSymbol^4",
            "OriginalItemName^4",
            "Sequence^4",
            "SwissProtID^4",
            "option.AntibodyProducts^4",
            "option.AntibodyRanges&Modifications^1",
            "option.Applications^4",
            "option.Conjugate^3",
            "option.GeneID^4",
            "option.HostSpecies^3",
            "option.Isotype^3",
            "option.Primary/Secondary^2",
            "option.Reactivity^4",
            "option.Search^1",
            "option.TargetName^1",
            "option.Type^4"
          ],
          "query": "Calprotectin",
          "default_operator": "AND"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "targeted_countries"
                ],
                "query": "All US"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the query slowed down considerably, am I doing this correctly? Is there a 
way to speed it up? I'm currently in the process of doing the boosting when I index the document, but using it in the query that way is best for the way my application runs. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query time boosting is used for assigning larger weight to a term. If you want to permanently boost a field, use [index time boosting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/boost-field.html). If you don't want to use this boosting all the time, then it makes sense to create a separate mapping just for it with `store: "no"` set.

Comment: Thanks Artur, my issue is the weight values are going to be changing frequently so I'm trying to avoid manually updating the mapping each time they change. I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to this so is there a way to get out of doing that? (for example just index a boost value like { "item_name" :  { "_boost" : "4", "_value" : "armenian hamster anti-cd95 monoclonal antibody, pe conjugated, clone jo2"}) would that work?

Comment: The boost is combined with other components (term frequency and normalization factor) and the result is stored in the index, so AFAIK it cannot be changed without reindexing. What causes the fields boosts to change? Maybe they are not the right tool for your problem?

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend query time boosting over index time boosting, for exactly the reason you state: flexibility. Also, index time boosting reduces the precision of the field length norms.  I think the reason your query has slowed down is because, instead of querying just the `_all` field, you are now querying many many fields.